# Rails CRUD feature specs (RSpec and Capybara)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following feature spec tests CRUD operations for the `users` resource in a Rails 4.2.8 application. It includes tests for filtering, sorting and pagination features of the `index` view.

The tests work. However, I would greatly appreciate your feedback and suggestions on how to improve the specs (e.g., efficiency, readability, maintainability, DRYness).

In the index view, the data is displayed within a table. In the show view, it is displayed within a definition list (`<dl>` tag).

```
# spec/features/user_crud_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

def find_by_i18n_title(i18n_key)
  # Bootstrap renames the "title" attribute to "data-original-title"
  find("[data-original-title='#{I18n.t(i18n_key)}']")
end

# Select items from select2 dropdowns. https://select2.github.io/
def select_select2_option(option_text)
  first('.select2-container').click
  find('li', text: option_text).click
end

# Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287911/6307730
def sort_order_regex(*sort_by_attributes)
  /#{User.order(sort_by_attributes)
         .map { |u| Regexp.quote(u.email) }
         .join(".+")}/
end

RSpec.shared_examples "sort link" do |link_text:, sort_by:|
  it "sorts by #{sort_by} when the #{link_text} link is clicked" do
    # Trigger the lazy creation of 2 more records, total count is now 3
    users
    visit admin_users_path
    # Check the record's order by matching the order of their e-mails (unique).
    initial_order = sort_order_regex(:first_name, :last_name)
    tested_order = sort_order_regex(sort_by)
    within_table "users_table" do
      expect(page).to have_text(initial_order)
      click_link(link_text, exact: false)
      expect(page).to have_text(tested_order)
    end
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_single_record do |slug|
  match do |page|
    expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 1)
    expect(page).to have_selector("tr#user_#{slug}")
  end
  failure_message do |page|
    "expected to find a single record in the page with slug #{slug}. " \
    "Found #{page.all("tr#user_#{slug}").count} records instead."
  end
end

describe "User admin CRUD", type: :feature, js: true do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }
  let(:user_with_associations) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    masters = FactoryGirl.create_pair(:master, users: [user])
    # Quote requires an associated user to be valid. The :quote factory creates
    # a user unless we pass an existing one as an argument.
    FactoryGirl.create(:quote, master: masters.first, user: user)
    user
  end
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user) }

  before(:each) { login_as(user) }

  describe "Index view" do
    let(:users) { FactoryGirl.create_pair(:user) << user }

    it "displays all existing users" do
      # Trigger the lazy creation of one more user with associations (to
      # ensure the associations appear in the index page)
      users = [user, user_with_associations]

      visit admin_users_path
      expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: users.count)

      users.each do |user|
        # <tr> must have user_x (x is the record slug) as DOM ID
        within("#user_#{user.slug}") do
          # OPTION 1
          expected_regex = /#{[
            user.email,
            user.role,
            user.full_name,
            CS.countries[user.country.to_sym],
            user.sangha,
            user.masters.map(&:name).join(' '),
            user.quotes_count
          ].join(".*")}/
          expect(page).to have_text expected_regex

          # OPTION 2
          # requires <td>s to have their corresponding attribute names as a DOM class
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".email", text: user.email
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".role", text: user.role
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".full_name", text: user.full_name
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".country",
          #                               text: CS.countries[user.country.to_sym]
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".sangha", text: user.sangha
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".masters",
          #                               text: user.masters.map(&:name).join(' ')
          # expect(page).to have_selector ".quotes_count",
          #                               text: user.quotes_count
        end
      end
    end

    it "loads the show view when the 'show' icon is clicked" do
      visit admin_users_path
      find_by_i18n_title("actions.show").click
      expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_user_path(user))
    end

    it "loads edit view when the 'edit' icon is clicked" do
      visit admin_users_path
      find_by_i18n_title("actions.edit").click
      expect(page).to have_current_path(edit_admin_user_path(user))
    end

    it "destroys the user when the 'delete' icon is clicked" do
      # Create a new user so the logged-in user does not get deleted
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      visit admin_users_path
      expect do
        within("#user_#{user.slug}") do
          page.accept_alert I18n.t("are_you_sure") do
            find_by_i18n_title("actions.delete").click
          end
        end
        # Redirect back to the index view after record is destroyed.
        # Must be inside the #expect block to ensure the DB operation is
        # finished before trying to count records.
        expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_users_path)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

    describe "sorting" do
      include_examples "sort link", link_text: "E-mail", sort_by: :email
      include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Role", sort_by: :role
      include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Country", sort_by: :country
      include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Sangha", sort_by: :sangha
      include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Quotes", sort_by: :quotes_count
    end

    describe "filtering" do
      it "filters by email" do
        # Trigger the lazy creation of 2 additional records. E-mails are unique.
        users
        visit admin_users_path
        fill_in "q_email_cont", with: user.email
        click_button "email_search_submit"
        expect(page).to have_single_record(user.slug)
        # Test the filter's "Clear" button
        click_on "Clear"
        expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: users.count)
      end

      it "filters by full_name" do
        # The logged in user (created by let!(:user)) has a different name
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user,
                                  first_name: "Unique",
                                  last_name: "Name")
        visit admin_users_path
        expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 2)
        fill_in "q_full_name_cont", with: "Unique Name"
        click_button "email_search_submit"
        expect(page).to have_single_record(user.slug)
      end

      it "filters by role" do
        # The logged in user (created by let!(:user)) has :admin role
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: :user)
        visit admin_users_path
        expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 2)
        select "user", from: "q_role_eq"
        # It auto-submits
        expect(page).to have_single_record(user.slug)
      end

      it "filters by country" do
        # The country of the logged in user is not "TH" (see the factory)
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, country: "TH")
        visit admin_users_path
        expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 2)
        select "Thailand", from: "q_country_eq"
        # It auto-submits
        expect(page).to have_single_record(user.slug)
      end

      it "filters by master (select box)" do
        # The logged in user (created by let!(:user)) has no masters
        master = FactoryGirl.create(:master)
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, masters: [master])
        visit admin_users_path
        expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 2)
        select master.name, from: "q_masters_name_cont"
        # It auto-submits
        expect(page).to have_single_record(user.slug)
      end
    end

    describe "pagination" do
      before(:all) do
        # Temporarily reduce the limit of users per page to avoid having to
        # create a large number of records.
        @original_max_per_page = Kaminari.config.default_per_page
        Kaminari.config.default_per_page = 2
      end

      after(:all) do
        # Restore original pagination settings
        Kaminari.config.default_per_page = @original_max_per_page
      end

      context "with a single record" do
        it "does not paginate" do
          visit admin_users_path
          expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 1)
          expect(page).to have_no_selector("ul.pagination")
        end
      end

      context "with 3 records and maximum records per page set to 2" do
        before(:each) do
          # Trigger the lazy creation of 2 more records, total count is now 3
          users
          visit admin_users_path
        end

        it "displays 2 records in the 1st page " do
          expect(page).to have_selector("ul.pagination")
          expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 2)
        end

        it "displays 1 record in the 2nd page" do
          within "ul.pagination" do
            click_link "2"
          end
          expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_users_path + "?page=2")
          expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 1)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#new view" do
    it "creates a new user" do
      visit new_admin_user_path
      expect do
        # Implemented in spec/support/helpers/capybara_fill_user_fields.rb
        fill_user_fields(valid_attributes)
        click_button "Create User"
        # Keep this inside the expect block to ensure it waits until the new
        # record is created before recounting records.
        expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_user_path(User.last))
      end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      expect(page).to have_text "successfully created."
      expect(page).to have_text "Name #{valid_attributes[:first_name]}"
    end
  end

  describe "#show view" do
    it "displays all public attributes" do
      # Create a record with all associations to ensure they appear on the
      # #show view
      user = user_with_associations
      visit admin_user_path(user)
      [
        "E-mail #{user.email}",
        "Role #{user.role}",
        "Full Name #{user.full_name}",
        "Sangha #{user.sangha}",
        "Country #{CS.countries[user.country]}",
        "State #{CS.states(user.country)[user.state]}",
        "City #{user.city}",
        "Phone Number #{user.phone_number}",
        "Facebook URL #{user.facebook_url}",
        "Masters #{user.masters.map(&:name).join(' ')}",
        "Quotes #{user.quotes_count.to_s}"
      ].each do |text|
        expect(page).to have_text text
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#edit view" do
    it "allows an admin to update all public attributes of the user" do
      # create two masters to be selected in the "Masters" multiselect box.
      masters = FactoryGirl.create_pair(:master)
      visit edit_admin_user_path(user)
      # Implemented in spec/support/helpers/capybara_fill_user_fields.rb
      fill_user_fields(valid_attributes)
      # Select 2 items from the "Masters" select box
      masters.each { |master| select_select2_option(master.name) }
      click_button "Update User"
      expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_user_path(User.last))
      expect(page).to have_text "successfully updated."
      expect(page).to have_text "Name #{valid_attributes[:first_name]}"
    end
  end
end
```